# Why I get different values from JS and PHP Mersenne Twister implementations?

Tags: php, javascript, random, mersenne-twister

1) 
In PHP when I use native php MT implementation

```
mt_srand(1); 
var_dump(mt_rand());
var_dump(mt_rand());
var_dump(mt_rand());
```

I get values

```
1244335972
15217923
1546885062
```

2) In this Mersenne Twister implementation
http://kingfisher.nfshost.com/sw/twister/
I run

```
$twister = new twister(1);
var_dump($twister->int31());
var_dump($twister->int31());
var_dump($twister->int31());
```

and get

```
1791095845
2135392491
946286476
```

3) In JS I use
http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/JAVASCRIPT/java-script.html

```
m = new MersenneTwister(1)
m.genrand_int31()
m.genrand_int31()
m.genrand_int31()
```

and get

```
895547922
2141438069
1546885062
```

How could it happens?

Actually, this in JS

```
m = new MersenneTwister(1)
m.genrand_int32()
1791095845
```

and this in PHP

```
$twister = new twister(1);
var_dump($twister->int32());
```

return the same value 1791095845, but only for the first call.

Comment: Am I missing something? Are you asking why a random number generator is generating random numbers?

Comment: Ah, ok I did miss that. D'oh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mersenne twister is a *class* of PRNGs, not a single algorithm. The Mersenne primes used in the algorithm may vary, and different primes will produce different results for the same seeds.

Comment: So then how can I get equal values for same given seeds on client and on server? Am I should implement MT algo myself?

Comment: Pretty much. Fortunately, it's not that hard.